# test if the python list items are positive only or negative only not both

Tags: python

I need to test if a list contain only positive numbers, or only negative numbers

for example:
if `[1, 5, 3]` return True
if `[1.2, -2, 5, -0.5]` return False
if `[-2, -4]` return True

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: The question is crystal clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if all elements in the list are on the same side of `0`.

```
def sameSign(l):
    return not min(l) < 0 < max(l)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/scjihJ)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use numpy you can do it like this :

```
arr = np.array(your_list)
res = np.all(arr>0) | np.all(arr<0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) builtin functions.

Examples of `any`:

```
>>> any(val < 0 for val in [1, 5, 3])
False
>>> any(val < 0 for val in [1, -5, 3])
True
```

Examples of `all`:

```
>>> all(val < 0 for val in [1, -5, 3])
False
>>> all(val < 0 for val in [-1, -5, -3])
True
>>> all(val > 0 for val in [1, 5, 3])
True
```